Why didn't C. Columbus use Ptolemy's measurements for Earth circumference (and other assumptions)
I listened on the French radio to a very interesting podcast on Christopher Colombus (France Culture, Christophe Colomb, l'envers du décor [fr]).
One of the recurring messages (and this is taught in schools I believe everywhere in Europe) is that he thought, and then really wanted to be in Asia (to have landed in India)1.
It made me wonder about the following points:

the shape and size of the Earth were well known at this time, at least since Ptolemy
what has been discovered so far (including India) was more or less correctly measured (in terms of distance), i.e. one would know that India from Europe is at $x$ days of travel, which makes it at $y$ distance from Europe
trigonometry was known and Columbus was a sailor who knew how to measure distances on the sea

What in the assumptions above is incorrect, so that he expected India to be about halfway closer than it would be from calculations? (to him or to other people involved in the preparation of his trip)

1 He even had a notary with him that would "confirm" that they were indeed in Asia.
Note: I considered asking the question on SE History but I feel that the exact question (what is wrong with the mathematical/physical assumptions I have) is closer to science history than to pure history. Please let me know if I should move it over there.

Note: In English we say (from the Latin version) "Columbus" for "Columb".

@GeraldEdgar: Thanks! I corrected my question

Because he did not believe Ptolemy's measurements. "Columbus believed the incorrect calculations of Marinus of Tyre, putting the landmass at 225 degrees, leaving only 135 degrees of water. Moreover, Columbus underestimated Alfraganus's calculation of the length of a degree... Columbus therefore estimated the size of the Earth to be about 75% of Eratosthenes's calculation, and the distance from the Canary Islands to Japan as 2,400 nautical miles (about 23% of the real figure)" see.

https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14047/why-did-columbus-think-the-earth-was-much-smaller-than-it-is/14050#14050


Earth's circumference is the distance around Earth. Measured around the equator, it is 40,075.017 km (24,901.461 mi). Measured passing through the poles, the circumference is 40,007.863 km (24,859.734 mi).1

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_circumference
Eratosthenes calculated the circumference of the Earth about 250 BC as 252,000 stadia. If a stadium was between 155 and 160 meters his error would be between - 2.4% and + 0.8 %.
The Indian Aryabhata calculated the diameter of the Earth about AD 525 as 1,050 yojanas.  Depending on the length of a yojana Aryabhata's figure might have been 5 %, 11 %, or 20 % too large.
Around AD 850 scholars of the Caliph Al-Mam'un calculated the circumference of the Earth, probably coming within 5 % to 15 % of the true value.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_circumference
However:

Posidonius calculated the Earth's circumference by reference to the position of the star Canopus. As explained by Cleomedes, Posidonius observed Canopus on but never above the horizon at Rhodes, while at Alexandria he saw it ascend as far as 7+1⁄2 degrees above the horizon (the meridian arc between the latitude of the two locales is actually 5 degrees 14 minutes). Since he thought Rhodes was 5,000 stadia due north of Alexandria, and the difference in the star's elevation indicated the distance between the two locales was 1/48 of the circle, he multiplied 5,000 by 48 to arrive at a figure of 240,000 stadia for the circumference of the earth.2 It is generally thought[by whom?] that the stadion used by Posidonius was almost exactly 1/10 of a modern statute mile.[citation needed] Thus Posidonius's measure of 240,000 stadia translates to 24,000 mi (39,000 km), not much short of the actual circumference of 24,901 mi (40,074 km).2 Strabo noted that the distance between Rhodes and Alexandria is 3,750 stadia, and reported Posidonius's estimate of the Earth's circumference to be 180,000 stadia or 18,000 mi (29,000 km).[6] Pliny the Elder mentions Posidonius among his sources and—without naming him—reported his method for estimating the Earth's circumference. He noted, however, that Hipparchus had added some 26,000 stadia to Eratosthenes's estimate. The smaller value offered by Strabo and the different lengths of Greek and Roman stadia have created a persistent confusion around Posidonius's result. Ptolemy used Posidonius's lower value of 180,000 stades (about 33% too low) for the earth's circumference in his Geography. This was the number used by Christopher Columbus in order to underestimate the distance to India as 70,000 stades.[7]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_circumference#Posidonius
And:

1,700 years after Eratosthenes's death, Christopher Columbus studied what Eratosthenes had written about the size of the Earth. Nevertheless, based on a map by Toscanelli, he chose to believe that the Earth's circumference was 25% smaller. If, instead, Columbus had accepted Eratosthenes's larger value, he would have known that the place where he made landfall was not Asia, but rather a New World.[23]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_circumference#Columbus's_error
Up until recently it was hard to longitude, distance from east to west, accurately.

In 1474, Toscanelli sent a letter and a map to his Portuguese correspondent Fernão Martins, priest at the Lisbon Cathedral, detailing a scheme for sailing westwards to reach the Spice Islands and Asia. Fernão Martins delivered his letter to the King Afonso V of Portugal, in his court of Lisbon. The original of this letter was lost, but its existence is known through Toscanelli himself, who later transcribed it along with the map and sent it to Christopher Columbus, who carried them with him during his first voyage to the New World.[7] Toscanelli had miscalculated Asia as being 5,000 miles longer than it really was, and Columbus miscalculated the circumference of the Earth by 25 percent: both of which resulted in Columbus not realizing initially he had found a new continent.[7]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paolo_dal_Pozzo_Toscanelli#Cartography
In medieval Europe "India" was a very vague geographical term.  The Third India included part of western Asia and Eastern Africa.  The Lesser India may have included Persia and it extended east to the Malabar coast in modern India.  The Greater India extended east from the Malabar coast and included much of Modern India, Indochina, and Indonesia.
And some people may have thought the Greater India may have included China, the Philippines, and Japan.
So when Columbus decided he had reached "India", he was imagining a much larger region than the Republic of India or the British ruled Empire of India.
Columbus might have had evidence that the Atlantic Ocean was only a few thousand miles wide and claimed that the unknown land to the west of it must be Asia.

In May 1476, he took part in an armed convoy sent by Genoa to carry valuable cargo to northern Europe. He probably visited Bristol, England,[27] and Galway, Ireland,[28] where he may have visited St. Nicholas' Collegiate Church.[29] It has been speculated he went to Iceland in 1477, though many scholars doubt this.[30][31][32][33] It is known that in the autumn of 1477, he sailed on a Portuguese ship from Galway to Lisbon, where he found his brother Bartholomew, and they continued trading for the Centurione family.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Columbus#Early_life
If Columbus did travel to Iceland, he could have learned of the Norse colonies in Greenland (which is geographically part of North America) and which had last been visited from Iceland only decades earlier.  And Columbus could possibly have learned of lands southwest of Greenland such as Helluland, Markland, and Vinland, lands which could be interpreted as northeast Asia.
And Columbus could have heard of driftwood and trees on currents from the west being washed up on beaches, or had other evidence of unknown land only a few thousand miles west of Europe which he would have claimed was the fabulously wealthy and exotic Asia.

Below is one of many quotes I found: The premise of the question is false. Columbus "did" use Ptolemy's distance for the earth's circumference, which is 28% smaller that the actual actual circumference.  Ptolemy's numbers were over 1,200 years old and accepted by many at the time. ....
If Columbus had used the larger number, he would have never tried to sail that far to Asia.
"In the second century CE (Common Era) in Alexandria, a philosopher named Claudius Ptolemaeus, or Ptolemy, revised Posidonius' calculations and set the earth's circumference at 28,985 kilometers (18,000 miles)—an error of nearly 28 percent. Because of Ptolemy's contributions to geography and cartography, his circumference was used throughout the Renaissance. It is believed that Christopher Columbus used Ptolemy's number to plan his voyage to the Far East. Everyone knows how that voyage ended—Columbus bumped into a continent that was hiding in the 28 percent error." http://www.geo.hunter.cuny.edu/~jochen/gtech201/lectures/lec6concepts/datums/determining%20the%20earths%20size.htm#:~:text=In%20the%20second%20century%20CE,in%20the%2028%20percent%20error.
